Gmail not receiving email HTML conforming to MIME standard
I'm currently developing a tool that sends emails to users via SMTP, including HTML content and a PDF attachment. I've been testing it with two different clients: desktop Outlook and web Gmail. The structure follows the MIME standard as detailed below.
Header
|From: email
|To: email
|MIME-Version: 1.0
|Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="boundary1";
Message body
|multipart/mixed --boundary1
|--boundary1
|   multipart/related --boundary2
|   |--boundary2
|   |   multipart/alternative --boundary3
|   |   |--boundary3
|   |   |text/plain
|   |   |--boundary3
|   |   |text/html
|   |   |--boundary3--
|   |--boundary2--
|--boundary1    
|Attachment1
|--boundary1

Referring to the answers here
Mail multipart/alternative vs multipart/mixed
This is my code
func (s *Smtp) SendMail(addr, from, to, subject, content string, attachments map[string][]byte) error {
    c, err := smtp.Dial(addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if host, _, err := net.SplitHostPort(addr); err != nil {
        return err
    } else if err := c.StartTLS(&tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true, ServerName: host}); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    //
    if err := c.Mail(from); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for _, addr := range strings.Split(to, ",") {
        if err = c.Rcpt(addr); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    //
    w, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    body := "test test test"
    // RFC 1046-style
    buffer := bytes.NewBuffer(nil)
    boundary := multipart.NewWriter(buffer).Boundary()
    boundary2 := multipart.NewWriter(buffer).Boundary()
    boundary3 := multipart.NewWriter(buffer).Boundary()

    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("From: %s\n", from))
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("To: %s\n", to))
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Date: %s\n", time.Now().Format(time.RFC1123Z)))
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Subject: %s\n", subject))
    buffer.WriteString("MIME-Version: 1.0\n")
    buffer.WriteString("Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf(" boundary=%q\n", boundary))
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary))

    buffer.WriteString("Content-Type: multipart/related;\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf(" boundary=%q\n", boundary2))
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary2))

    buffer.WriteString("Content-Type: multipart/alternative;\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf(" boundary=%q\n", boundary3))
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary3))

    buffer.WriteString("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n")
    buffer.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n")
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString(body)
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary3))

    buffer.WriteString("Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n")
    buffer.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n")
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString(content)
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString("\n")
    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s--\n", boundary3))

    buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s--\n", boundary2))

    if len(attachments) > 0 {
        for k, v := range attachments {
            buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s\n", boundary))
            buffer.WriteString("Content-Type: application/pdf\n")
            buffer.WriteString("Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n")
            fmt.Println(k)
            buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=%q\n", k))
            buffer.WriteString("\n") // this here
            encodedStr := base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(v)
            for i := 0; i < len(encodedStr); i += 50 {
                end := i + 50
                if end > len(encodedStr) {
                    end = len(encodedStr)
                }
                buffer.WriteString(encodedStr[i:end] + "\n")
            }
        }
        buffer.WriteString(fmt.Sprintf("--%s--", boundary))
    }
    //
    if _, err := w.Write(buffer.Bytes()); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    if err := w.Close(); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return c.Quit()
}

I've found that if I remove the newline character after // this and send it, web Gmail is able to receive the email, but desktop Outlook does not.
The SMTP server reports an error stating: "554 5.6.211 Invalid MIME content: the number of header objects (100001) exceeds the allowed maximum (100000)."
If I keep the newline character after // this, web Gmail does not receive the email, but desktop Outlook does.
Theoretically, according to the MIME standard, there should be an empty line between the header information (such as Content-Type) of each MIME part and its actual content. I believe this newline should be present.
I'm not sure why there is a subtle difference between the two scenarios. Am I missing something?
